# Eclipse: How to customize painting of markers on VerticalRuler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse plug-in that shows custom multi-line markers in Eclipse's own AbstractTextEditor.

Here is what I have so far:

- a custom marker with the super type "org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"
- an annotationType (org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes)
- a markerAnnotationSpecification (org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification)

This is all working well, my markers show up in the editor. But I need to customize the way they are drawn on the VerticalRuler, so they do not only show up as an icon, but as a vertical line spanning the affected source lines.

I know, that this can be done with Annotations by implementing IAnnotationPresentation and overwriting paint().

But how can I do this for markers?

*Edit*: Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Red bars on the left]

Comment: "but as a vertical line spanning the affected source lines." what do you mean? Can you post a screenshot describing your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by contributing a RulerColumn (extension point `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.rulerColumns`) and configuring `markerAnnotationSpecification` to *not* include `verticalRulerPreferenceKey` and `verticalRulerPreferenceValue` (so it will not be shown on the default  AnnotationRulerColumn).

In case someone also finds the documentation on how to best implement `IContributedRulerColumn` a bit sparse: it seems the way to go is to subclass `AbstractContributedRulerColumn` and have the methods delegate to a subclass of `AbstractRulerColumn`.

For example:

```java
public class MyRulerColumn extends AbstractContributedRulerColumn {
    private IVerticalRulerColumn delegate = new AbstractRulerColumn() { … }
    public void setModel(IAnnotationModel model) {
        delegate.setModel(model);
    }
    …
}
```

Customizing the appearance is then as easy as overwriting one of the paint… methods in the delegate.